# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException

Tags: symfony, debugging, bundle

I try to release my web application using Symfony 4.0.6 on Elastic Beanstalk of Amazon Web Service. However, I have a problem about "Script cache:clear returned with error code 255 !! (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)" when the application is deploying

I have updated the symfony/flex (v1.0.70 => v1.0.71) and I have checked it following.

```
$ composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader
~~~~
  - Removing symfony/process (v4.0.6)
Generating optimized autoload files
ocramius/package-versions:  Generating version class...
ocramius/package-versions: ...done generating version class
Executing script cache:clear [KO]
 [KO]
Script cache:clear returned with error code 255
!!  PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "DebugBundle" from namespace "Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle".
!!  Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace? in C:\Users\xsunt\PhpstormProjects\xsun\tv\4.0\src\Kernel.php:32
!!  Stack trace:
!!  #0 C:\Users\xsunt\PhpstormProjects\xsun\tv\4.0\vendor\symfony\http-kernel\Kernel.php(403): App\Kernel->registerBundles()
!!  #1 C:\Users\xsunt\PhpstormProjects\xsun\tv\4.0\vendor\symfony\http-kernel\Kernel.php(122): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeBundles()
!!  #2 C:\Users\xsunt\PhpstormProjects\xsun\tv\4.0\vendor\symfony\framework-bundle\Console\Application.php(64): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot()
!!  #3 C:\Users\xsunt\PhpstormProjects\xsun\tv\4.0\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(143): Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
!!  #4 C:\Users\xsunt\PhpstormProjects\xsun\tv\4.0\bin\console(39) in C:\Users\xsunt\PhpstormProjects\xsun\tv\4.0\src\Kernel.php on line 32
```

I think that we need to check three bundles following

```
class Kernel extends BaseKernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $contents = require $this->getProjectDir().'/config/bundles.php';
        foreach ($contents as $class => $envs) {
            if (isset($envs['all']) || isset($envs[$this->environment])) {
                **yield new $class();**
            }
        }
}

cat /config/bundles.php

    Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle::class => ['dev' => true, 'test' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle::class => ['dev' => true, 'test' => true],
```

Could you please give me an advice?

Comment: The error message tells the story.  You are trying to install with ---nodev but you are still accessing the DebugBundle.  Think you might need to adjust your composer.json file though I don't know exactly how.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am going to check it again.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you don't pass the `APP_ENV` environment variable, so the script `cache:clear` is running in dev mode.

You should run `APP_ENV=prod composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader`

This is also mention on https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment.html#c-install-update-your-vendors

Another option is to run `composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader --no-scripts`, with the extra flag no scripts will be executed, but I don't know if your application relies on scripts to be run.